# Are the graphs I sketched of the derivative of a function and the function correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

I know that when the function is increasing, the derivative is positive. What I am confused about for the first one is that when I am sketching the derivative, I don't know what direction it goes (even though i know it is positive). What I am thinking is that where the graph has a min or max, then the derivative must have an x-intercept there. That is how I came up with my graph for the first two questions.

For the third question, I tried doing the opposite. So the derivative is positive thus the function is increasing and vice versa. Where the derivative has an x-intercept, the function has a min or max but the question is still a little confusing to me.

Answer (score -3):

I think it would be helpful for you to discretize your graph along X axis and calculate the derivative using some finite differences formula.

Comment: it has to be a sketch. i do not have time on a test to do finite differences formula

Comment: So in this case, focus on the extreme values of the function f, the derivative there must be zero. Then consider the curvature as well, the more the function is convex, the more the derivative increases rapidly.

Comment: i mentioned in my question that i did that. i want to know if my answers are correct and if not then how can i fix it

Comment: Could you please post your answer using a paper with markers so as we can see the correspondences?

Comment: okay i will do that

Comment: i just updated it, sorry it took so long

Comment: i don't have a paper with markers but i drew dashed lines for min/max so you can see better what i am doing

Comment: i don't know how to flip the image so that it is right side up

Comment: i think i am correct

Comment: looking at the position of the zeros of the derivative, yoi are correct. You can have more accuracy by setting the derivative to the maximum where the function changes convexity.